# Flexbox "Holy grail" layout with footer next to sidebar instead of below

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I've used the "Holy grail" layout without any problems and managed to get a sticky footer with a fixed header. Styling is taken from https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/.

```
.HolyGrail {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%; /* 1, 3 */
  flex-direction: column;
}

.HolyGrail-header,
.HolyGrail-footer {
  flex: none; /* 2 */
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: #222222;
}

.HolyGrail-body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto; /* 2 */
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: var(--space);
}

.HolyGrail-content {
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: var(--space);
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
}

.HolyGrail-nav {
  order: -1;
}

.HolyGrail-nav,
.HolyGrail-ads {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  padding: 1em;
  background: rgba(147, 128, 108, 0.1);
}
```

However, I need to move the footer below the content but next to the sidebar. Moving the footer inside of the main block is probably not the way to go as I guess I need a wrapper around the content and footer. However, I'm not sure what I should be doing in the wrapper. This is what I have now but doesn't work.

```
.HolyGrail-content-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
}
```

The html is:

```
<body>
  <div class="HolyGrail">
    <header class="HolyGrail-header">
      Header.
    </header>

    <div class="HolyGrail-body">
      <div class="HolyGrail-content-wrapper">
        <main class="HolyGrail-content">
          <p>Line of text.</p>
          <p>Line of text.</p>
          <p>Line of text.</p>
          <p>Line of text.</p>
          <p>Line of text.</p>
          <p>Line of text.</p>
        </main>
        <footer class="HolyGrail-footer">
          Footer.
        </footer>
      </div>
      <nav class="HolyGrail-nav">
        Sidebar.
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/QWttptvPRplvHLk8MFRt?p=preview

Comment: The footer in the plunkr seems to be doing what your question asks for: The footer is below the content and next to the sidebar. Please provide more details.

Comment: The problem is that the sidebar and footer are not flushed to the bottom of the screen when there is not enough main content to fill the complete screen. Thus the sidebar should take the complete height (minus the header) of the screen. And the footer should be sticky to the bottom of the screen next to the sidebar or under the content where just the content and footer should be scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`height:100%` must be inherited from `html`, else it is 100% of nothing (body had no height set).

you `HolyGrail-content-wrapper` needs to be a flexbox too.

*Run snippet below in full page mode*

```css
html, body,.HolyGrail {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}
.HolyGrail {
  display: flex;
  /* 1, 3 */
  flex-direction: column;
}
.HolyGrail-header,
.HolyGrail-footer {
  flex: none;
  /* 2 */
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: #222222;
}
.HolyGrail-body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  /* 2 */
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: var(--space);
}
.HolyGrail-content {
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: var(--space);
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
}
.HolyGrail-nav {
  order: -1;
}
.HolyGrail-nav,
.HolyGrail-ads {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  padding: 1em;
  background: rgba(147, 128, 108, 0.1);
}
.HolyGrail-content-wrapper {
  flex:1;
 display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
}
```

```html
<div class="HolyGrail">
  <header class="HolyGrail-header">
    Header.
  </header>

  <div class="HolyGrail-body">
    <div class="HolyGrail-content-wrapper">
      <main class="HolyGrail-content">
        <p>Line of text.</p>
        <p>Line of text.</p>
        <p>Line of text.</p>
        <p>Line of text.</p>
        <p>Line of text.</p>
        <p>Line of text.</p>
      </main>
      <footer class="HolyGrail-footer">
        Footer.
      </footer>
    </div>
    <nav class="HolyGrail-nav">
      Sidebar.
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated the Plunkr and this works like a charm.